# "Provisioning agent not found" when closing Eclipse runtime

Tags: eclipse, runtime, eclipse-rcp, rcp, pde

When closing the runtime of my Eclipse plugin I get following error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2012-04-19 18:44:18.200
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Provisioning agent not found
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getAgent(P2TargetUtils.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getProfileRegistry(P2TargetUtils.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.cleanOrphanedTargetDefinitionProfiles(P2TargetUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDECore$1.saving(PDECore.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.executeLifecycle(SaveManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$1.run(SaveManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.broadcastLifecycle(SaveManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.save(Workspace.java:2375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor$5.run(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.pde.core 4 0 2012-04-19 18:44:18.201
!MESSAGE Provisioning agent not found
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.pde.core 4 0 2012-04-19 18:44:18.202
!MESSAGE Provisioning agent not found

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2012-04-19 18:44:24.278
!MESSAGE Problems saving workspace

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 2 1 2012-04-19 18:44:24.279
!MESSAGE Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.resources 2 566 2012-04-19 18:44:24.280
!MESSAGE Problems occurred during save.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Provisioning agent not found
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getAgent(P2TargetUtils.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.getProfileRegistry(P2TargetUtils.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.target.P2TargetUtils.cleanOrphanedTargetDefinitionProfiles(P2TargetUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.PDECore$1.saving(PDECore.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.executeLifecycle(SaveManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$1.run(SaveManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.broadcastLifecycle(SaveManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.save(Workspace.java:2375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor$5.run(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.core 4 0 2012-04-19 18:44:24.280
!MESSAGE Provisioning agent not found
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Eclipse version is:
Juno Release
Build id: 20120322-1740

Comment: You might be missing some equinox plugins, like org.eclipse.equinox.ds may be?

Comment: Considering http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#Why_won.27t_my_application_start.3F, is it possible you are stopping "`org.eclipse.equinox.ds`" too early?

Comment: Alexander, You are right, thank you, adding org.eclipse.equinox.ds did the trick. Any idea why it wasn't picked up by "Add Required Plug-ins"?
(Can you post the answer please, so I can acccept it?)

Comment: @Tobias: I have added a potential reason for the missing "`org.eclipse.equinox.ds`" package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alexander pointed out I was missing the equinox plugin org.eclipse.equinox.ds which was not added automatically by Eclipse, not even after "Add Required Plug-ins".

Answer (score 2):

As this [thread illustrates](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/834031/), when you are clicking "Add Required Plug-ins", and are still missing packages (like, in your case "`org.eclipse.equinox.ds`"), that can be linked to the type of project you are using:

> You'll do yourself many favors if you **change your build to a feature-based build and use the `org.eclipse.rcp` feature**: it Includes all the necessary bundles for an RCP app, including `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` and `.event`.